# CSV file having additional comma in the data

Tags: csv, unix, awk, sed

I have a CSV file which has some data that contains comma within it. I am trying to retrieve the data as a whole without considering the additional fields.

Input example

```
 id,name,marks,subject/s
 1, Dileep, Kumar, 78, Maths
 2, Pavan, Joshi, 76, Science, Social
 3, Naveen, 95, English
```

Can I remove the comma within the field since, the name is one column even though it has additional comma within it

output required -

```
 id,name,marks,subject/s
 1, Dileep Kumar, 78, Maths
 2, Pavan Joshi, 76, Science Social
 3, Naveen, 95, English
```

I know that removing comma for subjects doesn't make sense, but that is what I am asked for.

Please help me

Comment: Show us what you've done so far

Comment: and how one should deal with this line `2, Pavan, Bonny, 3 Joshi, 76, Industry, 100, -, Science, Social, 1` ? What will be the 3rd field in this case?

Comment: The proper solution is to use double quotes around any CSV field values which contain a literal comma.

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
awk  '$2~/[a-zA-Z]+/ && $3!~/[a-zA-Z]+/{$2=$2~/,/?$2:$2",";print;next} $2~/[a-zA-Z]+/ && $3~/[a-zA-Z]+/{sub(/,/,"",$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk  '
$2~/[a-zA-Z]+/ && $3!~/[a-zA-Z]+/{
  $2=$2~/,/?$2:$2",";
  print;
  next
}
$2~/[a-zA-Z]+/ && $3~/[a-zA-Z]+/{
  sub(/,/,"",$2)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
 id,name,marks,subject/s
1, Dileep Kumar, 78, Maths
2, Pavan Joshi, 76, Science, Social
3, Naveen, 95, English
```

Comment: Does this mean that all the second comma will be escaped ? what if the name is a single word which doesn't have a comma in it

Comment: @Dileep, if this is the case please update your question with sample of that.

Comment: @Dileep, please check my edited code now and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'id,name,marks,subject/s
 1, Dileep, Kumar, 78, Maths
 2, Pavan, Joshi, 76, Science, Social
 3, Naveen, 95, English' | sed -r 's/(^\s*[0-9]+,\s*[a-zA-Z]+),(\s*[a-zA-Z])/\1\2/g'
id,name,marks,subject/s
 1, Dileep Kumar, 78, Maths
 2, Pavan Joshi, 76, Science, Social
 3, Naveen, 95, English
```

Comment: shen, as you see, in the last entry the comma between Name and marks (Naveen and 95) is not present

Comment: @Dileep, thanks, already fix this issue. seems sed will match digit as \w too.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for patsplit() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    nf = patsplit($0,nums,/ [0-9]+, /,rest)
    $0 = ""
    for (i=0; i<=nf; i++) {
        $0 = $0 nums[i] gensub(/, /," ","g",rest[i])
    }
    print
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
 id,name,marks,subject/s
 1, Dileep Kumar, 78, Maths
 2, Pavan Joshi, 76, Science Social
 3, Naveen, 95, English
```